# No puedo hacer click en el bottom sidebar en Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, click

Estoy montando una web en Wordpress y tengo un problema con el bottom sidebar, en la barra inferior donde están los widgets, puedo añadir y modificarlos sin problema, pero luego los enlaces no funcionan ni un formulario que he añadido en el widget, es como si fuera una imagen, no deja interaccionar con nada ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser?

Este es el fragmento de código donde ocurre el problema:

```
<div id="bottom" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Conductor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Animales peligrosos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Seguridad privada</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deportistas</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Y este el `css`que se le aplica:

```
#bottom {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, primero de todo bienvenido. Te sugiero que le des un vistazo a este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tu pregunta ahora mismo es demasiado generica, deberias ponernos algo de código o indicarnos mejor cual es el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida, lo siento si mi pregunta no ha sido muy buena, es la primera vez que participo por aquí. Ya me han comentado más abajo cual es el problema, aunque no se muy bien como hacerlo. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes la siguiente regla `css`:

```
#bottom {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

que aplicas en ete div:

```
<div id="bottom" class="cmsmasters_color_scheme_footer">
```

Esto provoca que el contenido sea movido atrás y por lo tanto los enlaces no sean accesibles, simplemente elimina el `id` del div:

```
<div class="cmsmasters_color_scheme_footer">
```

y funcionarán tanto los links como el formulario.

Otra solución es eliminar esta regla del fichero `wp-content/themes/medical-clinic/theme-framework/theme-style/css/style.css` (esto es recomendable sólo si no se utiliza en otro sitio)

Y como recomendación añadiría que edites la pregunta añadiendo el el código `css`y el `HTML`para que la pregunta no sea eliminada y pueda ser útil para alguien en un futuro y no sólo para ti ahora.

Comment: Ok! lo entiendo, pero donde lo modifico, porque lo único que hice fue añadir los widgets.

Y lo de css y html te refieres a que lo ponga como etiqueta, no?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con otra soución. Te recomiendo encarecidamente que modifiques la pregunta para hacerla útil para los demás usuarios, añade información, fragmentos de código, etc...

Comment: Ok, gracias, he modificado la regla CSS en el editor de Wordpress cambiando el z-index a 0 y ya está

Comment: @Zafiro ¿has resuelto el problema?

Comment: Sí, cambié el z-index a 0 y ya funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: muchísimas gracias por toda la ayuda, ya he visto que has modificado la pregunta, así la verdad está muchísimo mejor. Intentaré ir mejorando, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Cierto @Mariano, basta con modificarla, de hecho zafiro ha optado por esa solución.

Comment: @ErnestoRM recién leí bien tu respuesta y vi que ya lo tenías, perdón... entiendo que estés cuidando al resto de las páginas, pero creo que hay más posibilidades de que rompa un script que usa ese id... Y siempre puede crear una regla por encima de la que ya tiene, que sólo aplique a esta página. Yo hubiese recomendado eso como primera opción.